# how i can check that a .json file gets loaded when a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, json

> how can i a check that a .json file gets  loaded  when a page is  loaded.
>
> Is there any way to apply logs as we do in python by using " console.log"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. console.log(dataToLog)

In browsers that support console (I.E. Chrome, Fireforx, Opera...)

Answer (score 0):

View ajax calls in the console

For WebKit select Network tab and click XHR

For Firefox select Net tab and click XHR